# jQuery scrollTop(value) function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scrolltop

I am trying to scroll a div after an ajax call but it does not work. The solution mentioned in [Jquery .scrollTop() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578901/jquery-scrolltop-not-working) and [jQuery scrollTop function not working after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247276/jquery-scrolltop-function-not-working-after-ajax-call) doesn't work either.

The problem is with this function call :

```
$("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")
.scrollTop($("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")[0].scrollHeight);
```

It doesn't scroll the div. Also there are no errors in the console.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <div id="admin">
          <div class="boxcontent" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">
               <div id="logadmin" clear="all" style="white-space: pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;"></div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function waitForMsg()
{
   $.get("poll.php", function(data)
   {

    if(data!='')
    {
           document.getElementById('logadmin').innerHTML=data;
           console.log("scroll height:"+$("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")[0].scrollHeight); 
// Works perfectly. Scroll height gets printed in console
           $("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin").scrollTop($("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")[0].scrollHeight); //Does not work!!! No error in console.

            /*setTimeout(function() {
        $("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin").scrollTop($("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")[0].scrollHeight);
}, 10);    }*/

    }
    setTimeout("waitForMsg()",1000);
    }).fail(function() {
   setTimeout("waitForMsg()",5000);
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.boxcontent {
font-family: arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
color: #333333;
height:95%;
width:95%;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:auto;
padding:7px;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;
background-color: #ffffff;
line-height: 1.3em;}

.panel-body {
height: 80vh;
overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Comment: What is that extra `, 10);}` ?

Comment: That part is commented. Its the solution mentioned in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578901/jquery-scrolltop-not-working . But that is not working.

Comment: Well just a tip, I noticed your selector is pretty inefficient. Should just be `$("#logadmin")` since that's an ID selector.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user221458 That wasn't a solution, it was just advice. Otherwise I would have posted an answer.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Can you provide [verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code please? Otherwise we're just blindly suggesting answers here since we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have already provided a verifiable code. What else do you need?

Comment: what is .scrollHeight ? make sure that it is proper number.

Comment: @qubit It is a proper number. I am also printing it using console.log() and it is working perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
function waitForMsg() {
  $.get("poll.php", function(data) {

    if (data != '') {
      document.getElementById('logadmin').innerHTML = json['msg'];
      setTimeout(function() {
          $("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin").scrollTop($("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")[0].scrollHeight);
          }, 100);

    }
    setTimeout(waitForMsg, 1000);
  }).fail(function() {
    setTimeout(waitForMsg, 5000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Definitely this will cause an error because you are not closing the bracket in this code $("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin" [0].scrollHeight) . But even if I put the bracket, it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you add that and try it again? That was just a typo.

Comment: Could you try adding a `console.log` inside firsr setTimeout

Comment: I added console.log inside  setTimeout before and after the scrollTop function call and both console.log gets printed but the scroll doesn't happen and there is no other error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99453/discussion-between-void-and-user221458).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are trying to scroll the right element. If `div class="boxcontent` is overflowing then you have to scroll this one not `$("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")` & if you want to scroll to top just passing 0 will be enough.

```
$("#admin .boxcontent").scrollTop(0);
```

Here is [SAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/vmhz39e9/)

I guess this part has some logical error

```
$("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")[0].scrollHeight .
```

This will actually give you the height of `#logadmin` and

```
$("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin").scrollTop($("#admin .boxcontent #logadmin")[0].scrollHeight);
```

if executed will take you to bottom rather than taking to the top.So when scrollbar is at the bottom it wont scroll & neither will throw an error

[Explore More](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/vmhz39e9/1/)

**EDIT**

Try by changing the `height:95%` to `height:somepixelvalue;` Infact you can use this `max-height:sompixelvalue` and remove the percentage. Like

```
max-height:200px;
```

Also height of `#logadmin` will be enough and you can use this snippet

```
var a = $("#logadmin").height()
$("#admin .boxcontent").scrollTop(a);
```

[Scroll Bottom](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/qt9mkynb/2/)

Please check this [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/pbPNvOzEUD2zPXkiO492?p=preview) have included all changes

Comment: I tried that before posting this question. But that doesn't work too.

Comment: can you please post the HTML and css also ?

Comment: I have posted the css.

Comment: I want to go to bottom and not to the top. I have tried keeping the scrollbar at different positions but it doesn't work. It only gets resized (becomes a bit smaller) as new content arrives in logadmin and does not scroll.

Comment: I tried changing the height to pixel value but unfortunately this also doesn't work..

Comment: you should also add height to #admin
 #admin{
 height:100%;
 }